# Python OpenCV set timeout on VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv

Trying to set a max timeout for VideoCapture to catch the exception and print a message if the stream is down. For example, I need it to try for 10 seconds and then assume the stream is offline. I have the following code so far.

```
import cv2

try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://Username:Password@IP_ADDRESS:PORT")
    print("Stream found.")
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
except:
    # It actually never reaches the exception
    print("Stream not found.")
```

Edit: Tried to simplify the answer below and it kind of works as expected but still with its own timeout decision.

```
import cv2
import time

try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://DNA:DNA2020!@98.173.8.28:5514")
    try:
        success, video_frame = cap.read()
        if success:
            print('Frame read')
        else:
            print('No frame read')
    except cv2.error as e:
        print(f'CV2 Exception: {str(e)}')

    cap.release()
except:
    print("Stream not found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

When opening the stream you only get a video object. Then you have to start reading the frames from the video object. This will tell you if there is a video stream.

TIMEOUT: The code stops if during 10 seconds no frames have been received.

RESET TIMEOUT: If within the 10 seconds new frames are being received then receiving resumes and the timeout will be again 10 seconds.

I have tested this code on a video file. I think it should work on your camera also.

```
import cv2
import time

try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://Username:Password@IP_ADDRESS:PORT")
    print("Stream found.")

    stream_ok = True
    while True:
        try:
            success, video_frame = cap.read()
            if success:
                print('Frame read')
                frame_ok = True
                # show frame
                cv2.imshow("Image", video_frame)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
            else:
                print('No frame read')
                frame_ok = False
        except cv2.error as e:
            print(f'CV2 Exception: {str(e)}')
            frame_ok = False

        if stream_ok:
            if not frame_ok:
                # start of missing video
                stream_ok = False
                no_frame_start_time = time.time()
        else:
            if not frame_ok:
                # still no video
                if time.time() - no_frame_start_time > 10:
                    print('NO VIDEO - CAPTURE ABORTED')
                    break
            else:
                # video restarted
                stream_ok = True

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

except:
    # It actually never reaches the exception
    print("Stream not found.")
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to not mess the comments. Any further suggestions?

Comment: You have simplified the code but removed the timeout code. The above code times out on 10 seconds. Which of course makes it again more complex. NO FRAMES ->start of timeout.... FRAMES AGIAN-> reset timeout start reading again..... TOO LONG NO FRAMES-> abort

Comment: Or do you only want to check on timeout directly at the start of the program?